# Access is denied error while accessing web services from vbscript

Tags: vbscript, soapui, xmlhttprequest

I am getting the error Access denied 403 while accessing the web services from VB script.Please see the below code

```
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
http.open "GET", "http://*************/enterprise/soap?ServiceName=RequisitionService&wsdl", FALSE
http.send '"'<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header><soapenv:Security><soapenv:UsernameToken><soapenv:Username>bijay.bhushan.singh</soapenv:Username><soapenv:Password>Newuser!123</soapenv:Password></soapenv:UsernameToken></soapenv:Security></soapenv:Header></soapenv:Envelope>'"'
WScript.Echo http.responseText
```

when i am acessing the same web services from SOAP UI i am able to access with below code.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Security>
<soapenv:UsernameToken>
<soapenv:Username>bijay.bhushan.singh</soapenv:Username>
<soapenv:Password>YmlqYXkuYmh1c2hhbi5zaW5naDpOZXd1c2VyITEyMw==</soapenv:Password>
</soapenv:UsernameToken>
</soapenv:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
```

even i tried with encrypted password in VBscript code but still i am getting the same issue.if i am able to access from SoapUI then i think i am doing something wrong in this VBS. kindly suggest me any solution for this

Answer (score 2):

Go to preferences > Proxy Settings > Enter your domain username and password.

Hopefully it should work

Answer (score 0):

i am able to resolve the issue passing username and password with http.Open as a parameter.